# How to share imports between modules?

Tags: python

My package looks like this:

[image]

These helpers, since they are all dealing with `scipy`, all have common imports:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to extract them out, and put it somewhere else, so I can reduce the duplicate code within each module?

Comment: Not really, each module needs to explicitly import the stuff it needs. However, this doesn't impact efficiency since the interpreter will not re-load modules that have already been loaded (unless explicitly told to do so via the `reload` function).

Comment: There are way to do it with `importlib`, but you would spend more time getting it right than you would save in typing/maintenance.

Comment: @rbp I just thought maintaining duplicate code is not really a good thing.

Comment: Sure, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a great principle, but it doesn't really apply to "header" stuff, like imports.

Comment: Don't hate me but it's possible to do: `import builtins; import os; builtins.os = os`. *Runs away banging the door*.

Comment: @PM2Ring I disagree. It is essentially standardising a set of dependencies, which is a good thing.

Comment: Sure, it's _possible_, just not necessarily a good idea. :)

Comment: @AndyHasIt: Fair point. But replacing 2 simple `import` lines with approximately the same amount of code to pull in the imported stuff with some fancy trick doesn't really give much benefit, and it hides those dependencies. I prefer modules to explicitly state their dependencies; YMMV.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Whoa! That's evil. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring for two or 3 lines I agree. However I do see science modules with several lines of imports, not all from stb lib, in which case there may be a valid case for tidying it. Although several lines of import is probably a sign of code smell. I've edited my answer to show a balance between explicit and concise, though there are cons to that approach too.

Comment: @rbp just looked at `importlib`, I'm on python 2.7, it seems not well supported.

Comment: I use it all the time. works fine.

Comment: I'm with PM 2Ring on this. Keep it as it is, trying to 'standardize' things like imports is overkill imho.

Comment: @PM2Ring point 2 of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Explicit is better than implicit.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a file called `my_imports.py` which does all your imports and makes them available as `*` via the `__all__` variable (note that the module names are declared as strings):

File `my_imports.py`:

```
import os, shutil
__all__ = ['os', 'shutil']
```

File `your_other_file.py`:

```
from my_imports import *
print(os.curdir)
```

Although you might want to be explicit in your other files:

File `your_other_file.py`:

```
from my_imports import os # or whichever you actually need.
print(os.curdir)
```

Still, this saves you having to specify the various sources each time — and can be done with a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is my tweak,

[image]

Create a `gemfile` under the package dir, like this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
```

Then, for other files, like `app_helper.py`

```
from .gemfile import *
```

This comes from here [Can I use __init__.py to define global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383239/can-i-use-init-py-to-define-global-variables)