# Using seperate files per function - global import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, dependencies, global

I've been wondering, if using multiple subfiles in a project to make the code look clean, why I have to **import each module** e.g. logging or time **in each subfile explicitly**. is there no way to make the **subfile.py** aware of the imports of **main.py**. See an example below where I want to use import time globally

**main.py**

```
import logging
import time
from subfile import myfunc

myfunc("Test")
```

**subfile.py**

```
import logging

def myfunc(var):
    logging.info("entered myfunc")
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Variable: {}".format(var))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better when all dependencies are explicit. Let's imagine that `subfile` implicitly uses `time` from `main`, like you want. This causes problems:

1. You can't unit-test `subfile` anymore, because it can't work separately from `main` and dependencies defined there. You would have to `import time` in the testing module. Now `main` and `tests` both have that import, instead of just `subfile`.
2. If (for some reason) you decide to remove `import time` from `main`, `subfile` becomes broken, but there's no way you can know that, unless you run some code analyser on the whole project. The current model allows you to find missing dependencies just by scanning one file and the directory structure.

If you really have **a lot** of common dependencies (e.g. you need `time`, `logging`, and 10 other packages in every file), this thread: [How to share imports between modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102484/how-to-share-imports-between-modules) can help with managing that.