# How can I access (global) variable defined at __init__.py?

Tags: python

Here is the code structure:

```
 my_project
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── util
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utility.py
```

When I run a program via `python3 my_project/main.py`.

I defined `my_variable = 5` in `my_project/__init__.py`.

I want to access this `my_variable` at `main.py` and `utility.py`.

But have no idea how to do that....

I followed [Can I use __init__.py to define global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383239/can-i-use-init-py-to-define-global-variables), but it doesn't work for me (Cannot import project directory folder... it occurs an error : `ImportError: No module named 'MY_PROJECT_DIR'`..

Could you help this out?

Comment: Could you expand on *"it doesn't work"* with a [mcve]?

Comment: `import my_project; print(my_project.my_variable)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can not import `my_project` in `main.py`... it said, `No module named 'my_project'`...

Comment: Python doesn't search in `..` for modules.

Comment: @user3595632 move into the parent directory of `my_project`

Comment: If you `from my_project import main` at the REPL (as in the answer you linked) it will work.

Answer (score 2):

For this you should be using relative import. Also python treats scripts and modules differently

content of `my_project/__init__.py`

> my_variable = 5

content of `my_project/util/utility.py`

> from .. import my_variable
>   print("my_variable", my_variable)

content of `my_project/main.py`

> from . import my_variable
>   print("my_variable", my_variable )

running this as module

```
$ python3 -m my_project.util.utility
my_variable 5
$ 
$ python3 -m  my_project.main
my_variable 5
```