# ImportError: cannot import name some_name from '__main__'

Tags: python, import

A variable `isDevelopment` is inside the `manager/__init__.py` file:

```
 isDevelopment = True
```

Within the same directory a file `fusion.py` attempts to import it at the file level:

```
from . import isDevelopment
```

Note: `pycharm` is ambivalent to it: the import is not flagged in any case:

[image]

When attempting to import it from some other location e.g. `..` pycharm does complain:

[image]

When running

```
 python3 manager/fusion.py
```

the following occurs:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'isDevelopment' from '__main__'
```

Another attempt per one of the suggestions:

```
from ..manager import isDevelopment
```

This results in:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Why is this attempted `import` not working - and what needs to be changed?

Comment: Have you tried `from my_package import isDevelopment` or `from ..my_package import isDevelopment`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy updated the question

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy  `from ..manager import isDevelopment
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: @Kristian np: i just deleted mine in turn. thx for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./test.py
./manager/__init__.py
./manager/fusion.py
```

### __init__.py

```
isDevelopment = True
```

### ./manager/fustion.py

```
from . import isDevelopment

def checkDevelopment():
    print("isDevelopment = {0}".format(isDevelopment))
```

### ./test.py

```
import manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("isDevelopment = {0}".format(manager.isDevelopment))
    manager.checkDevelopment()
```

### Execute

```
python3 ./test.py
```

### Output

```
isDevelopment = True
isDevelopment = True
```

### Question

Are you attempting to execute manager/fusion.py to set the module or do you want it to be part of your executable application? If you simply want to know the value of isDevelopment within the manager module, that can be achieved. If you want an executable function contained in manager explore entry points using setup.py

Comment: Thanks for the investigation: still uncertain what is happening inside my module so it does not work there: but you have established it _should_ in general case.  I'll probably award as soon as I can .. and hope to come about what is going on at some point. I gave up for now and made it a module-local variable

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` is used to initialize the package. According to documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> Users of the package can import individual modules from the package

You don't import what is in `__init__.py`, it's run automatically when you do an import.

> In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package

As `isDevelopment` is **not** a module you cannot import it! If you have another module `fusion2.py` you could import it with

```
from . import fusion2
```

and there you should be able to see `isDevelopment`.

Comment: If that import were simply removed:  `NameError: name 'isDevelopment' is not defined`  Also `pycharm` marks it in red

Comment: Many places in this codebase there are variables being imported: can you please explain further?

Comment: Variables in __init__.py? You should probably expand your question first. It is complicated to answer something we cannot see and evaluate. But from what I see, you don't import variables from __init__.py.

Comment: I was not focusing on `__init__.py` as being different in that way: will double check if am using variables from it in other places

Comment: Seems should be ok according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383281/1056563    `You should be able to put them in __init__.py. This is done all the time.`

Comment: No. Read the answer you are linking again. The are running "from mypackage import mymodule". They *do* import a module, *not* a constant

Comment: `from mypackage import MY_CONSTANT`