# Complaining not a "package" though there is a __init__.py file in the folder

Tags: python, flask, package, blueprint

The Following is my code hierarchy.

[image]

I am trying to create a package for my project, "UIGenerator" but it is giving me following error.

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from UIGenerator import app
  File "/Users/______/Desktop/UIGenerator/UIGenerator/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from site.routes import site
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site.routes'; 'site' is not a package
```

Here is the code for run.py =>

```
from UIGenerator import app

@app.route('/')
def test_connection():
    return "<h1>Connected<h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There is nothing in `site =>__init__.py` file and in `site=>routes.py`, I have some sample code to test-

```
from flask import Blueprint

site = Blueprint('site', __name__)

@site.route('/site')
def site():
    return "this is test for site package"
```

The following is my code for the UIGenerator's **init**.py file =>

```
from flask import Flask
from site.routes import site

def getApp():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(site)
    return app

app = getApp()
```

Can anyone give me any clue, please.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to build a Python package with you files, [like outlined here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). This will be better in the long run if you want to scale this project up, and will [allow you to declare things in **init**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383239/can-i-use-init-py-to-define-global-variables)

That being said, I think you can get your setup working by moving this chunk of code

```
def getApp():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(site)
    return app

app = getApp()
```

to the run.py file for the time being.

Comment: thank you for the reference though it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is what I found out from a different post. In my site=>routes, I declared a global blueprint with the name, `site` and later I created a `site()` function which somehow masked my site blueprint. If I just renamed the site method name, it works.